# Easy creation of new file upload directory per entry instead of per channel?

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager, files

I want to know if there is a way to create unique file upload directories that are assigned PER ENTRY, instead of assigned to a channel?

I have a channel named "Projects" and each entry will have a slideshow of images. There are a LOT of entries in this channel, which means a LOT of images... and I'm worried about naming conflicts, organization, and ultimately confusing my users.

I realize I could just create a new folder and choose to upload images there when creating an entry, but this is too complicated to expect my users to do when they are creating entries.

Is there a way to create the upload directory on the fly and assign it to the entry?  I need some way of organizing things so that each entry has a unique folder for uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload a slideshow images per entry and you want separate directories per entry. You can simply use channel images plugin. It will create separate directories for each entry and you can also use image functions as well.
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-images-ee2

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look at this as an option.  I was hoping there was some way to achieve it without an addon, but it looks like EE doesn't work that way.

Comment: You are right. EE doesn't work that way. Instead of that, If you don't want to use an addon, You have to create each folder manually, create file manager preference, assign the preference to channel. That is a long process. So, use of an addon is the best solution.